# CSS grid layout: Is it possible to make one of items 100% width over the grid?

Tags: css, layout, multiple-columns, css-grid

I am looking for a way to make one of the grid items 100% width, but I don't know if this is possible width CSS grid layout in the first place.

Here's an image of the layout I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

There's a container with the width of "1040px" and there's a grid inside, where the number of columns is 12. The text part with the white background takes up the 6 columns, and as you can see, both the images take up 8 columns in the grid. What I want to achieve here is that they overflow the grid and fit the window size.

Is there any way to achieve this with CSS grid layout? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "overflow the grid"?

Comment: Also the pictures doesn't take 8 columns, they are span across more wide area.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59174442/8620333

Comment: Seems to me you **don't** want 12 columns in your grid, you want **14 or 16**.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Not quite. I'm sorry, but I forgot to mention in the post that there's a container with the grid in it, and I want the images to overflow the grid and the container when they still take 8 columns as shown in the image.

Comment: @Gaben Yes. Forgive me if I didn't explain well. but if you know what I mean, what I'm saying is that I want the images to take 8 columns in the grid and then overflow the grid and the container(the grid with the blue lines is the whole container), and stick to the sides of the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a whole page a `.container` and then add 2 more columns:

1. Left side
2. Right side

Both of which should have their `width` set either to `auto` or `1fr` (and the other 12 columns should have predefined `width`).

Then you should add "spacers" for all the grid items that you want positioned in certain way.

---

In the end you will have 14 columns, where left and right ones have different width.
You shouldn't try to "get out of grid", you should just set the grid to your liking.

Comment: I feel like I'm getting there thanks to your idea, but I can't figure out where to put the images. The layout should be 1fr - 12columns - 1fr based on your method, correct? Since the images span across 12 columns - 1fr, I don't know how to put the images in the layout.

Comment: OK, I just saw your edit. So, the layout abode can't be created as far as your comment goes. Thank you.